ピクセルの総数を特定のアスペクト比の解像度に収める数式を作りたい
質問内容
タイトル通りなのですが、あるピクセル数を特定のアスペクト比な解像度に収めるにはどうしたらいいのか知りたいです。
状況
NES解像度: 256 x 240
指定アスペクト比: 16 : 9
なぜこの行為を行いたいのか？
NESのような解像度のようなフレームバッファを作成してそれをアップスケーリングして
ウインドウに描画することでNESのようなドット絵が動くゲームを作りたいです。
自分で解像度を決めるのもいいですが、NESは4:3なので現代の16:9の比率には合わないのでこの質問を立てました。
知りたいこと
上記の状況で指定アスペクト比の場合でのNES解像度の総数(61440)はどんな解像度の値なのかを算出するコードの書き方
考えたこと
１，ピクセルの総数を(16 * x) * (9 * y)という数式でx,yの値を１ずつ増やしてピクセル総数の値に近づける　※下記提示コード参照
２，以下のように取りえず実装したのですがコンソールログの値のアスペクト比を検索すると3 : 2と表示されてしまうため、以下のコードは間違えです
提示コード内容
上記の考えたこと部の1のを使ってNES解像度のピクセル総数かどうかを比較しています。
コンソールログ
336 , 189

提示コード
全文です。ライブラリ未使用
#include <iostream>


int main(void)
{
    int nesWidth = 256;
    int nesHeight = 240;

    int aspectRatio_x = 16;
    int aspectRatio_y = 9;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        int pixel = (aspectRatio_x * i) * (aspectRatio_y * i);

        if(pixel >= (nesWidth * nesHeight))
        {
            std::cout<<(aspectRatio_x * i) << " , " << (aspectRatio_y * i)<<std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}



アスペクト比とは何ですか？ (336 : 189)  は (1621 : 921) つまり (16 : 9)ではありませんか？「検索すると」の意味が不明です。

336 x 189 >= 256 x 240 となっているが、これは収まっているのかな？

自然数 w と h に対して、 w : h = 16 : 9 かつ w × h = 61440 になるようなものを求めたい、という意味だと解釈しました。
つまり、w = 16h / 9 かつ wh = 61440 という連立方程式を解けば良いです。ただしそのまま解くと、w = 330.4...、h = 185.9... となって自然数になりません。つまりこのふたつの式を完璧に満たすことはできないので、どちらかの条件を諦めることになります。
あとは「収める」というのを質問者さんがどう解釈するか次第です。たとえば 256 x 240 の縦横どちらかに余白を追加して 16:9 にするにはどのくらい余白を入れればよいかという問題にしても良いですし、w × h = 61440 を保ったままなるべく w / h を 16 / 9 に近づけるといくつになるかという問題にしても良いです。いずれにせよ解くことができます。今回はアップスケールを考えたいとのことなので、おそらく前者の考え方になろうかと思います。

その辺は数学的理論だけで検討すると失敗します。もう少し「機器側の事情」って奴を考慮に入れる必要があります。
NES (Nintendo Entertainment System) とは日本で言えば「ファミコン」です。この当時の出力先はアナログブラウン管テレビでした。ファミコンの内部で RF 信号に変換している関係で、ファミコン内部の VRAM 上の全領域がブラウン管テレビに表示できるようなことはありませんでした。だいたい９０％くらいしか出力できなかったらしいです。
NES のピクセル数 256x240 というのも実際にはかなり微妙で、実際に見える範囲は 256x224 であると解釈すべきかもしれません。ファミコンの縦解像度224px説の考察 上記ディスプレイの特性を生かして全 VRAM がブラウン管に映らないことを利用してスクロールをスムーズに見せることが可能としていました。
他にも、はたして画面上の１ピクセルは本当に正方形なのか？ NES 側の1ピクセルつまりブラウン管上の１ピクセル相当のアスペクト比と（必ずにじむので１ピクセルってのが定義しづらい）、現代 PC 向け完全デジタル伝送した画面の液晶ディスプレイの１ピクセルのアスペクト比は同じなのか？　とか
（提供者側がこれがベストだと思っていたとしても）利用者側で縦横比は自分で設定したいとか
なのであまり難しいことを考えずに「横：２５６ドットを利用者の指定したサイズに拡大する」「縦：２４０ないしは２２４を選択可能にして、それを利用者の指定したサイズに拡大する」で十分なのでは？　みたいな気がします。つまり縦拡大比と横拡大比が別途設定できればヨシ。
それで横伸びし過ぎとか縦伸びし過ぎとか、そう思うなら提供者側としては「推奨サイズ」って奴を提供しておけば十分かと。それを利用者が採用するか否かは利用者側の選択に任せておけばいいです。
